# prepare IM room for rocket.chat users?

Tags: rest, rocket.chat

I'm currently looking at the rocket.chat [REST-API](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/) and can't find a way to prepare a IM-room for two users. Both users do not have the permission to create a direct message (missing create-d). But I do have a privileged admin/bot-user, which should connect them, at any time.

I tried to [im.open](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/im/open/) a roomId with both user id's (I've noticed, that direct messaging rooms are groups, without name and concat(userid1, userid2) as id). But I always receive:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": "[invalid-channel]",
    "errorType": "invalid-channel"
}
```

The `im.create` method cannot be used, since I can't tell the API which two users I want to connect (the first is always "me"/the logged in user).

Using `group.create` would create a room with 3 members (user1, user2, me). Which isn't what I want either.

Is there a way to create a IM between two users? Without the permission "create-d" on these two?